# Script to echo out range of dates

Tags: linux, bash, date

I've been trying to get a script to print out a range of dates from a start date then the day after up to the present day.

Example:

```
Backup-2011-06-14
Backup-2011-06-15
Backup-2011-06-16
```

Had a idea below but doesn't even slightly work, any ideas?

```
start=$(date +%F --date="2011-06-14")
echo "$start"
current=$(date +%F)
echo "$current"
end=$(date +%F)

while [ "$start" != "$current" ]; do
    echo backup-$(( $(date --date="$start" +%F) + $(date +%s --date='1 day') ))
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351282/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-dates-given-starting-and-ending-dates-using-awk-of/4351948#4351948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date math in bash is difficult.  But the `date` command does support simple addition or subtraction from today's date.  So a different approach is necessary in your case.  First, determine the number of days for which you want to output these dates, then output the dates as they relate to today's date.

```
#!/bin/bash
days=$(( ($(date +%s)-$(date +%s --date="2011-06-14"))/86400 ))

while [ $days -gt 0 ]; do
    echo backup-$(date --date="-$days days" +%F)
    days=$(($days-1))
done
```

Comment: thats great... works a charm - No I need to try to work out how to add it to my merge backup script :-(