# How to create missing records within date-time range in pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have input records of the form

```
2013-07-09T19:17Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T03:17Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T21:17Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T16:17Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T16:14Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T16:16Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T01:17Z,f1,f2
2013-07-09T16:18Z,f1,f2
```

These represent timestamps and events. I have written these by hand, but actual data should be sorted based on time.

I would like to generate a set of records which would be input to graph plotting function which needs continuous time series. I would like to fill in missing values, i.e. if there are entries for "2013-07-09T19:17Z" and "2013-07-09T19:19Z", I would like to generate entry for "2013-07-09T19:18Z" with predefined value.

My thoughts on doing this:

1. Use MIN and MAX to find the start and end date in the series
2. Write UDF which takes min and max and returns relation with missing
   timestamps
3. Join above 2 relations

I cannot get my head around on how to implement this in PIG though. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate another file using a script (outside pig)with all time stamps between MIN and MAX , including MIN and MAX. Load this as a second data set. Here is a sample that I used from your data set. Please note I filled in only few gaps not all.

```
2013-07-09T01:17Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T01:18Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T03:17Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T16:14Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T16:15Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T16:16Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T16:17Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T16:18Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T19:17Z,d1,d2
2013-07-09T21:17Z,d1,d2
```

Do a COGROUP on the original dataset and the generated dataset above. Use a nested FOREACH GENERATE to write output dataset. If first dataset is empty, use the values from second set to generate output dataset else the first dataset. Here is the piece of code I used on these two datasets.

```
Org_Set = LOAD 'pigMissingData/timeSeries' USING PigStorage(',') AS (timeStamp, fl1, fl2);
Default_set = LOAD 'pigMissingData/timeSeriesFull' USING PigStorage(',') AS (timeStamp, fl1, fl2);
coGrouped = COGROUP Org_Set BY timeStamp, Default_set BY timeStamp;

Filled_Data_set = FOREACH coGrouped {
    x = COUNT(times);
    y = (x == 0?  (Default_set.fl1, Default_set.fl2): (Org_Set.fl1, Org_Set.fl2));
    GENERATE FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN(y.$0), FLATTEN(y.$1);
};
```

if you need further clarification or help let me know

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rags answer, you could use the [`STREAM x THROUGH`](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigStreamingFunctionalSpec) command and a simple awk script ([similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351282/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-dates-given-starting-and-ending-dates-using-awk-of)) to generate the date range once you have the min and max dates. Something similar to (untested! - you might need to single line the awk script with semi-colon command delimitation, or better to ship it as a script file)

```
grunt> describe bounds;
(min:chararray, max:chararray)
grunt> dump bounds;
(2013/01/01,2013/01/04)
grunt> fullDateBounds = STREAM bounds THROUGH `gawk '{
  split($1,s,"/")
  split($2,e,"/")
  st=mktime(s[1] " " s[2] " " s[3] " 0 0 0")
  et=mktime(e[1] " " e[2] " " e[3] " 0 0 0")
  for (i=st;i<=et;i+=60*24) print strftime("%Y/%m/%d",i)
}'`;
```