# How to iterate through dates from start date to end date?

Tags: bash, date, unix

I have to move files over a very large date range (from `20141212` to `20170202`).

How do I iterate over all of these dates in the format `%Y%m%d` in bash on a unix machine?

I'm using the `gnu` version of `date`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a sequence of dates given starting and ending dates using AWK of BASH scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351282/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-dates-given-starting-and-ending-dates-using-awk-of)

Comment: my dates are in a different format.  And I don't want to use `awk`.

Comment: Use `date`, and whatever format you want to with it.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Do you have GNU `date`? What kind of unix are you interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a hilariously inefficient way of doing things:

```
for x in {20141212..20170202}
do
date --date="$x" &> /dev/null && whateverCommand "$x"
done
```

For a quicker way:

```
x=0
while :
do
thisDate=`date --date="20141212 $x days" +%Y%m%d`
whateverCommand $thisDate
if [[ $thisDate = 20170202 ]]; then break; fi
((x++))
done
```

Comment: why is it inefficient?

Comment: @guimption It runs through all the numbers from 20141212 to 20170202, checks if they're valid dates, and then runs the commands. Since most of the numbers are not valid dates, there's a lot of wasted time.

Comment: oh, then this is not ideal.  there must be a way to just loop through dates using the `date` command.  but how?

Comment: @guimpton: that depends on which implementation of `date` you use. (Gnu and BSD are popular options; BSD is what is usually found on a Mac.) If you want platform-independent it's harder.

Comment: gnu is the version i'm using

Comment: @guimption To be clear, the second way I listed doesn't have this inefficiency and is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a 3rd party tool ([dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/)):

```
$ dateseq -i %Y%m%d 20141212 20170202 -f %Y%m%d
20141212
20141213
20141214
20141215
20141216
20141217
20141218
20141219
...
```

The `-i` and `-f` options are necessary to deal with your specific format.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.